# Adding a featured image to atom feed

Tags: feed

I'm using my own theme for a blog. In my `functions.php` file I added a function:

```
function featuredImageToRSS($content)
{
    global $post;
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $content = '<image>' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID) . '</image>' . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

And used the following filters to apply it to the feeds:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'featuredImageToRSS');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'featuredImageToRSS');
```

However those are not called in the atom feed (`http://example.com/feed/atom/`).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I should have used the [`atom_entry()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/atom_entry/) hook.

So the following code will add your post thumbnail to your atom feed:

```
function featuredImageToRSS()
{
    global $post;
    $content = '<image>';
    if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
        $content .= get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
    }
    $content .= '</image>';
    echo $content;
}


add_action('atom_entry', 'featuredImageToRSS');
```